# Use Javascript to do a google search within a function to retrieve images to display in HTML markup

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to do something like this:

JavaScript

```
$scope.getSearchResults = function(searchString) {

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Do a google image search with searchString
    var currentUrl = searchOutput;
    $scope.googleSearchResults.push(currentUrl)
  }
}
$scope.getSearchResults('Mountains');
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="imageURL in googleSearchResults| limitTo: 5">
    <img ng-src="{{imageURL}}" />
</div>
```

So basically, using JavaScript or Angular or something to search google images, and grab the urls of the first however many you want? And `googleSearchResults` would either have an object of each image or even just a url of the image to display in the html?

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'd need to make a call to the Custom Google Search API:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. Use ajax to pull a search result from google as an html document then use the DOM of that page to find the images and store them in your array.